# jQuery doesn't find tags except html

Tags: jquery, element

I'm making Rails 3.1.1 app and trying to add some jQuery code to it.
jQuery didn't seem do anything so I added border to all elements:

```
jQuery("*").css("border", "5px solid red");
```

When reloaded page, only html had that border. I can manipulate for example text color of all elements with jQuery via html-tag, but not spesific element id or class.

I know for sure that Javascript is functional and jQuery library is being loaded:

```
javascript:alert($);
```

brings:

```
function (selector, context) {
   return new jQuery.fn.init(selector, context, rootjQuery);
}
```

Why can't I access to elements?

Comment: It seems that rails causes problems. Not sure what is going on, but when I include jQuery to html outside rails it works just like it should.

Comment: Problem solved, because javascript files are loaded in head tag, body doesn't exist yet there for it only adds border to html. I feel kinda stupid.

Comment: It's okay -- we're all kinda stupid sometimes. Could you post your solution as an answer, and check the check-mark next to it to accept it? This might help someone in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap your init function inside `$(document).ready();` like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // your code here will get executed
    // when the document finishes loading.
    jQuery("*").css("border", "5px solid red");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate for each item: http://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 0):

You can access all elements, `$("*")` will do that.

If you want to access an element by id use [the `#` prefix.](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

To access by css-class use [the `.` prefix.](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

To access by html tag type (tagName) [use just the name](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/). eg

```
$('#mybox') //selects tags with id = 'mybox'

$('.myclass') //selects tags with class = 'myclass'

$('input') //selects all <input> tags
```

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: I know how to use selectors, for example  $("#title").css("background","red") doesn't do a thing eventhough div with id 'title' exists

Comment: @Aleksi then you have a very unusual case. Something is missing. What happens if you `alert($('#title')[0].outerHTML);` ?

Answer (score 0):

tell the response from that :

```
if (jQuery) {  
    alert('1');
} else {
    alert('0');
}
```

Comment: try jQuery("*").css("border", "solid 5px  red");

Answer (score 0):

You should check, when you call this function. You should add this funcionality on event, when all document is loaded. Check this code:

```
function init(){
     jQuery("*").css("border", "5px solid red");
}

window.addEventListener('load', init, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, because javascript files are loaded in head tag, body doesn't exist yet there for it only adds border to html.